# Reducing image bit depth

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bit

I'm working on 800 x 800 pixels images with a bit depth of 24 (**PNG** format). I assume it means 3 x 8 bits. These images are just black and white (0 or 255).
I want to reduce this depth to 8 bit because*, when I process this images in matlab,* I create a 800 x 800 x 3 matrix which has a bigger computational cost than computing 2D matrix.

My idea was to subset the first layer of the matrix in **matlab** but it seems that I've lost the information because I've nothing left in my matrix.

```
`Im4=Im4(1:800,1:800);`
```

Any idea ?

I'm new to image processing and I may not know the basics...

Comment: Matlab can and does save images in `double` format, which means that it really does not matter the bit depth when storing them (it matters but matlab will handle it). It will definetly not create a 800x800x3 matrix unless those 24 bits per pixel are not actually the bit depth but the 3RGB channels for colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgb2gray` is probably the safest way to convert an M-by-N-by-3 image into M-by-N.

Comment: But, the OP claims that the image is 24bit depth, not RGB! If what he wants is to change the bit depth then `gray2ind(I,256)` is the solution, not `rgb2gray`!!

Comment: Let's wait for a clarification from the OP, then.

Comment: Given that the answer was accepted, I can only assume it worked fine for the OP?

Comment: Yes it did work fine for me ( I don't have enough reputation yet to vote up). Maybe the image was RGB (even if it only has 2 colors, black and white) ? I don't know much about images.... I'm still learning.

Comment: @Sarahdata, i guess you have gained enough reputation to vote up. Voting up privilege is given when you have 15+ rep. you may try it :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai, that's right, I can vote up now ! Thanks for reminding me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

this is just an alternative (since you are new at matlab image processing its nice to know different methods)

```
gray_scale = Im4(:,:,1);
```

This method only works because your image is already grayscale (this likely means red=green=blue). What the code says is from `Im4` take `all rows` and `all columns` of `channel 1` and store it in variable named `gray_scale` Channel 1 for an RGB image refers to the Red channel.

also the other comments were talking about rgb images or 24bit grayscale. an easy way to check is to take the ORIGINAL image (before processing) and type `size(MY_IMAGE_NAME_HERE)` this should give you 2 or more numbers.

1. number of rows
2. number of columns
3. if it is there gives the number of channels, color images usually have 3. If there is no 3rd number that means you have a 2d array that is grayscale